# Stealthing a port

Tags: attack-prevention, router

I ran a ShieldsUp port scan on my home router and found that all of ports 1 to 1056 were 'stealth' (connection times out) **except for port 1024**.  I know my router runs CWMP for management but this uses port 7547 which times out, so I imagine the router only listens to the ISP's addresses.

Port 1024 gives 'no route to host', suggesting the router tries to connect but nothing is listening.  I'm guessing the router is trying to send the connection to a non-running service within itself, as I don't see it would pick a random external connected device.

I don't imagine this is a huge security hole but I tried using port forwarding to send port 1024 to a random port on a nonexistent IP address in the far DHCP range.  Of course this still gives 'no route to host', but may be safer.

Is the port forward safer, and external does anyone know what this port 1024 route might be?